# How to iterate through directory and move particular files to a different folder

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a directory setup as follows:

```
/A001/A001_C001/A001_C001.mov
/A001/A001_C002/A001_C002.mov
--
/A002/A002_C001/A002_C001.mov
/A002/A002_C002/A002_C002.mov
--
..etc.
```

I need to write a script that can MOVE all files *.mov files to a different folder:

```
/mov/A001_C001.mov
/mov/A001_C002.mov
/mov/A002_C001.mov
/mov/A002_C002.mov
..etc.
```

Any ideas? I've just started learning shell-scripting and there are a lot of files that I need to migrate to a single directory.

Comment: We are not a bash script writing service.  We can only help you write the script yourself.

Comment: Hint: use find and mv

Comment: I used find and mv in my first attempt, but the iteration didn't work properly. Sorry for asking this noob question, but as i wrote previously i'm not familiar with the shell scripting syntax yet. Thx anyway for your hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't that difficult to google:

```
find src/dir/ -name '*.mov' -exec mv {} target/dir/ \;
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345714/recursively-moving-all-files-of-a-specific-type-into-a-target-directory-in-bash)